# Populate ListBox Based on Cell Values

Tags: excel, vba

I am populating a listbox based on

```
With lbInterviews
   .RowSource = "=Interviews!A2:P50"
End With
```

However, how would I do it so it only populates based on if a cell is equals to something e.g.

Only populate this list box, if the cell in sheet: Interviews, column: F is equals to textbox1.text

Comment: What if you just loop and populate the listbox that way?

Comment: Do you have any references to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're talking about a list box in a userform, if so, I hope this works for you ...

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    For i = 1 To 10
        If UCase(Left(Sheet1.Cells(i, 1), 3)) = "YES" Then
            ListBox1.AddItem Sheet1.Cells(i, 1)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the gif really helps

Comment: quick question, what is the '3' referring to, on the 3rd line?

Comment: @BCLtd that’s the 2nd parameter to the LEFT function which stipulates how many characters to get from the left hand side of the given text. So much to learn.   Glad I could help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

just an example

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    With sh
        LR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    lC = 0
    With Me.ListBox1
        .ColumnCount = 2
        .RowSource = ""
        For r = 2 To LR
            If Left(sh.Cells(r, 1), 1) = "P" Then ' <<< to changed condition
                .AddItem
                .List(lC, 0) = sh.Cells(r, 1)
                .List(lC, 1) = sh.Cells(r, 2)
                lC = lC + 1
            End If
        Next
        If .ListCount = 0 Then MsgBox "No data found"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: lC is a counter for listbox rows, the first row num is zero